# Is there a way to add new tabs to a tabController on another thread through invokes?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I am making a WinForms browser in c# that uses a tab system. To prevent links that open in a new tab from opening a new window without the browsers UI I made a LifespanHandler. The problem is that when the Invoke runs it errors

```cs
tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(lastIndex, "New Tab");
```

even though it is running the function that the new tab button runs. Here is the code

LifespanHandler:

```cs
class LifespanHandler : ILifeSpanHandler
        {
            public event Action<string> requestNewTab;
            public bool DoClose(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
            {
                return true;
            }

            public void OnAfterCreated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
            {

            }

            public void OnBeforeClose(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
            {
                
            }

            public bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
            {
                requestNewTab?.Invoke(targetUrl);
                newBrowser = null;
                return true;

            }
        }
```

The part that makes a tab on the tabController:

```cs
        public void newTab(String url)
        {
            LifespanHandler lifespanHandler = new LifespanHandler();
            lifespanHandler.requestNewTab += newTab;
            var lastIndex = this.tabControl1.TabCount - 1;
            this.tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(lastIndex, "New Tab");
            this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = lastIndex;
            tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = "New Tab   ";
       {
```

I tried making it a function that calls newTab but  with same result.
The error:
`System.ArgumentException: 'Controls created on one thread cannot be parented to a control on a different thread.'`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try using a **MethodInvoker** so using different threads would not be a problem for calling a UI object in a different thread.

```
    private void MyFunction(string url)
    {
        MethodInvoker inv = delegate
        {
          LifespanHandler lifespanHandler = new LifespanHandler();
          lifespanHandler.requestNewTab += newTab;
          var lastIndex = this.tabControl1.TabCount - 1;
          this.tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(lastIndex, "New Tab");
          this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = lastIndex;
          tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = "New Tab   ";
        };

        this.Invoke(inv);

    }
```

Comment: Instead of it throwing an error, It opened the thing I was using to open the popup/link that opens in new tab.

Comment: Not sure what are you referring with the "thing"